# SSIS Package connectivity issue

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am facing issue regarding connectivity of SSIS package. I have created SSIS package which import and export data on nightly basis. It is working on our server but one of our client is facing below issue:

```
    SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ".

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "XXXXXXX" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

component "OLE DB Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

One or more component failed validation.

There were errors during task validation.
```

I have verified connectivity of database from that server by using Management tool and it works well.

Please let me knw if someone faced this this type of issue.

Thank you...

Comment: I have seen a similar issue when having the connection as a command line parameter. The problem then was that the validation used the connection string stored in the OLE DB component and not the one in the parameter.

Comment: Have you verified connectivity at the time you experience the error? Have you checked SQL Server logs at the time of the error? Maybe a backup is occurring or something. You need to look at logs, logs, logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it there were some issue regarding connectivity of SQL database. Thanks to all for help.